# In Excel selecting an item from row when cell matches the first item in that row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have a LIST of 5 optional sizes.  There are several numbered mating parts that coincide with each of the sizes forming a pair.  Any 1 of the mating parts can go with a chosen size, but only 1.  Some of the numbered mating parts for one size use a same number as one of the numbered mating parts for another size.

I want to be able to select 1 of the 5 sizes, and the next cell for inputting thee the mating part number list limited to the mating part number included in the row associated with the appropriate size.  How can I do that?  My table looks like this:

```
Size    Mating parts                                
12      03  04  06  08  10  12  14      
16      08  10  12  14  16  18  20      
20      10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24  26
24      16  18  20  22  24  26  28  30  
28      24  26  28  30  32  34  36  38
```

The 5 sizes are 12, 16, 20, 24 and 28.  And the Mating part 2 digit numbers are in the rows to the right of the list. Some mating part numbers are redundant to mating part numbers in other rows.  They're different mating parts, just use the same number.

A user will select a size (12, 16, 20, 24 or 28), then move to a different cell to input the matching part number in it's own drop-down selection list.  This 2nd list should be limited to the row of data to the right (in the table) of the size.

Optional:  If someone manually selects 03 (for example) after choosing size 28 (from the size drop-down), I would want my formula to alert that these are not matching.

Comment: After posting the table is messed up. If you copy/paste this into excel, then add an empty row between size 20 and 28. Then carry down from the size 20 row, from the 2nd 24 and the remaining numbers to the right. The new (missing) row should read should read like this:  24  16  18  20  22  24  26  28  30.  [The leading 24 is the size].

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with data validation.

I'm going to assume your data is in cells A2:J6 (headers in row 1)

In one cell k2 use data validation and only allow a list

```
source: =$A$2:$A$6
```

For the second cell say L2 use a list with a condition in it

```
source: =IF(K2="",B1,OFFSET(A1,MATCH(K2,A2:A6,0),1,1,9))
```

This will give the row you need and the 9 cells next to it (the most numbers you have to the right of the initial number selected.

You could also do this with named ranges to make it a little neater but it works exactly the same.

Note if someone changes the first cell it won't automatically update the second one so there is still a chance for mismatched data if the second cell is set and the first is then changed.

If you need more instruction or explanation let me know.

[image]

Comment: Your formula does something, but it is not working correctly.  Probably due to my inability to explain.  I loaded a new worksheet with the data in the cells as you mention to test it to confirm.  No go.  Since you've done this let me explain a little better.  If size 20 is chosen, the next entry box (the next cell) *should* have a drop-down "list" of these options: 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, or 26.  The drop-down should not include any number less than 10 or higher than 26.  I changed your 4 to 9 because size 20 has 9 options (B-J).  Thanks for your help, you're getting me there!

Comment: I updated the formula because there was an error in that it didn't work if it was put in when k2 was blank.  I also added an image of where to put the formula in as it doesn't go in the cell block but in data validation.